SwiftUI ScrollView cannot click content on custom defined safe area
On my app I have a floating button. Because I don't want that this button to obstruct contents, I placed it on .safeAreaInset(egde: bottom) { }. ScrollView handles this safe area, and allow user to scroll extra distance.
However there is a problem I could not fix. The content on the safe area is not clickable.
On the example below, even though the buttons are visible on the bottom of the screen, they cannot be clicked because they are on the safe area.
Is there any fix or alternatives to achive the behaviour I want?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(1...100), id: \.description) { i in
                    HStack {
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                print("\(i) clicked")
                            },
                            label: {
                                Text("Button \(i)")
                            }
                        )
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Description \(i)")
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, alignment: .trailing) {
            Color.red.frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Maybe I don't understand the question well enough, but in my tests I can click on any
button, including those at the bottom of the screen.
On MacOS 15, Xcode 16, target iOS-18, tested on real iOS device and MacCatalyst.
What system are you using/targeting?

@workingdogsupportUkraine I successfully reproduced this on iOS 17.4, simulator.

how about when you use iOS-18?

@workingdogsupportUkraine I was using Xcode 15.4/iOS 17.5.
On Xocde 16/iOS 18, the behviour just like what I wanted.
On Xcode 16/iOS 17.5 they are not clickable.

The safe area cannot be any shape you want - it must be rectangular.
An alternative way to achieve this is by putting padding on the VStack, and put the red circle in a simple overlay.
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach(Array(1...100), id: \.description) { i in
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        print("\(i) clicked")
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("Button \(i)")
                    }
                )
                Spacer()
                Text("Description \(i)")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .padding(.bottom, 75) // <--- here
}
.contentMargins(.bottom, 75, for: .scrollIndicators)
.overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
    Color.red.frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding(.trailing)
}

Note that I also added .contentMargins(.bottom, 75, for: .scrollIndicators) to make the scroll indicator stop just above the red circle, recreating the same effect that safeAreaInset would have created.
